# Setting onClick function in Android Studio (Kotlin) shows an error message

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am building a little app in Android Studio using Kotlin. In one of my activities I have a button which when pressed I want it to call a function. For this I use the onClick attribute in the activity_main.xml `android:onClick=""`. What I want to be able to do is display some information based on the user inputs and update a textView in the same activity.

What I am doing now is setting the onClick attribute to `android:onClick"getResult"`.
The issue I run into is that it requires to have a parameter `'public void getResult(android.view.View)'` and what I don't know how to do is what parameter to pass as `android.view.view` in my getResult() function when I call it in my code.

Here is the complete signature of getResult()

```
fun getResult(view: View){
    //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: It is the view clicked

Comment: How do I reference that in code? If I put something like ```View(this)``` the app crashes.

Comment: Use `view.method()` but you have to cast it. Better way is to use in `button.setOnClickListener` avoiding the use of `android:onClick` in the xml.

Comment: Ok thank you for the information. I will look into ```button.setOnClickListener```.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to use:

```
/** Called when the user touches the button */
fun getResult(view: View){
    //view.method()
    //(view as Button).method()
}
```

The method you declare in the `android:onClick` attribute must have a signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:

- The value for this attribute must be the name of the method you want to call in response to a click event.
- The method is hosted in the Activity
- Be public
- Return void
- Define a `View` as its only parameter. **This will be the `View` that was clicked**.

You can also declare the click event handler programmatically settign the [**`View.OnClickListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)):

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
button.setOnClickListener {
    //..
}
```