# Button Onclick Kotlin use two parameters

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-studio

I am a beginner at XML and Kotlin and I have a button in xml and I want to call a function when it's pressed using android:onclick="". According to the post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018605/22258446, this function can only have one parameter being (view: View). I want to call a Segment Analytics Track call when this button is pressed to track a journey. This track call (I think) needs to have analytics: Analytics as a parameter to the function it's contained in.

```
fun ButtonClick(view:View){
            analytics.track("Products" buildJsonObject {
                put("productType", "Savings")
            })
        }
```

If I add in the (analytics: Analytics) to the parameters of ButtonClick it makes the app crash when I click the button. If I don't have it, the track call doesn't work and the app won't build.
I would preferrably have it as

```
fun ButtonClick(view:View, analytics: Analytics){
            analytics.track("Products" buildJsonObject {
                put("productType", "Savings")
            })
        }
```

Comment: Data binding cannot create your Analytics object instance for you. You need to set it up according to the documentation of whatever library you're using, so it will be available as a property in your Activity or Fragment class. Then your first code block above would be fine, because it would just be accessing the `analytics` property that you have already set up in your Kotlin code.